# Using a game controller for Windows 8 apps

Tags: windows-8, game-controller

I have a Xbox360 wired game controller pluged in a Windows 8 computer.  It is working correctly with games.  However, I would like to use it with Windows 8 apps in general.

As Windows 8 navigation works in general with the keyboard, can it work in general with a Game Controller?

If not, is there other solutions/device to control a Windows 8 app remotely?

Comment: Kinda - and no, not really. Microsoft sells a specific XBox controller for Windows. I have not tried it on Windows 8 as I don't have one. http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/xbox-360-controller-for-windows/C8G-00004

Comment: This is what I have.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Xpadder](http://www.xpadder.com/). It simulates keyboard presses and mouse movement. But you have to create your own profile for Windows 8 or find one on the web.